# How to set timezone Globally in angular 2

Tags: angular, timezone, utc

in my project i need all my time in timezone/utc **-02:00**

since there are many area in project which uses time it's bit difficult to convert in every place like

```
moment(d).utcOffset('-02:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Can i have this timezone set globally?

Comment: You can use injectable service for that.

Comment: Use Pipes.. You can refer to [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) and [Date filtering and formatting using pipe in Angular 2(+)](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should do is write a proxy Date class which should extend from Date class in angular and wherever you are doing a `new Date()`, it should be calling your Date proxy class rather than the angular Date class.